# Spring MVC 4 REST with protocol buffers not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Spring MVC 4's Rest templates to support google protocol buffers as message format. I have am following this post on Spring framework blog
[spring-mvc-google-protocol-buffers](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services)
I checked out the sourceCode trying to implement it in my environment.

I have two issues- I cannot get it to compile when I turn Java.version to 1.6 and i cannot get it to work as a webapp (don't know what 
will be the context-root of the converted war file)

-Details-
I have a requirement to make this code work as a web-app and deploy on java6 container (weblogic 10.3.6 -servlet 2.5 compliant)

So i changed the java 8 features from the codebase to make it Java 6 compatible. 
The only problem is when I change the pom.xml's following section

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

to change the java.version to 1.6 value, then try to do mvn clean install , the DemoApplicationTests class fails to compile with this error.

```
-google-protocol-buffers-master\src\test\java\demo\DemoApplicationTests.java:28: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor RestTemplate(java.util.List<org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter>) is not defined
[ERROR] location: class org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```

The following link shows that Spring codebase normally doesn't have any Java 8 specific source code so not sure why this code only compiles in Java 8
https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following link shows how to convert a spring boot application to a WAR app.
I did change the pom.xml packaging option to war. 
The code gets build by mvn clean install without issues and the .war file gets generated.
But there's no web.xml - so i cannot tell what will be the context-root of the deployed web app. 
I either way deployed the webapp on weblogic 10.3.6 ( which is java 6 compatible)
and it deployed fine.

But when I run the DemoApplicationTests (that I have changed to point straight to the URL 
using this call (got the context-root from the weblogic console by clicking on the deployed web app)

```
ResponseEntity<CustomerProtos.Customer> customer = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "http://127.0.0.1:7001/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/customers/2", CustomerProtos.Customer.class);
```

### I keep getting 404 not found error.

I have put up my changed code here.
https://github.com/robinbajaj123/spring-and-google-protocol-buffers

Your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to convert the Spring Boot app to also be a valid Servlet application. If you were using Servlet 3 or later and chose a `.war`-based deployment from [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) you'd get a ServletIntializer which is a Java class that is the programmatic equivalent of `web.xml`. Since you're using 2.5, not 3.0, you need an explicit `web.xml`. You might check out this sample on how to get a Boot app hoisted up in a Servlet 2.5 environment, [though using Servlet 2.5 is *not* recommended!](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy/blob/master/spring-boot-legacy/docs/sample-web.xml). It's worth mentioning that Servlet 3.0 support was introduced in 2009..

Finally, this code uses Java 8 lambdas. You'll need to replace the lambdas with Java 6-equivalent code. One example I see is:

---

```
@Bean
CustomerRepository customerRepository() {
      ...
```

---

The last line in the `@Bean` definition returns a lambda: `customers::get`. Replace it with:

---

```
final Map<Integer, CustomerProtos.Customer> customers = 
 new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, CustomerProtos.Customer>();

return new CustomerRepository() {

    public CustomerProtos.Customer findById(int id) { 
     return customers.get( id) ;
    }
};
```

---

Similarly, replace the `forEach` method in the `List` w/ an old-school for-in loop:

```
for (CustomerProtos.Customer c : Arrays.asList( ... )) { 
    customers.put(c.getId(), c);
 }
```

Comment: I have put in the web.xml as you suggested. When I deploy the webapp it shows the 
Mapped URL path [/customers/{id}] onto handler 'customerRestController'
But still when I run the DemoApplicationTests against the URL 

http://localhost:7001/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/customers/2

I get the ERROR - HttpClientError 404 Not Found
I have pasted full logs at http://paste.ubuntu.com/13966788/

I have put a default "hello world" index.jsp in the context root and that gets served without problem so i know i am using the right context root.
Not sure what could be the problem now..

Comment: I have also committed my code changes here 
https://github.com/robinbajaj123/spring-and-google-protocol-buffers/

Comment: one more observation - i have to generate the .war file with java.version at 1.6 in pom.xml <properties> section because I am running on Java6 in weblogic 10.3.6 container.

But when the running the DemoApplicationTests client I cannot compile the code with 1.6 setting, I have to change that to 1.8 to get it to compile

With 1.6 setting it still gives compile error -
no
 suitable constructor found for RestTemplate(java.util.List<org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter>)

full message is pasted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/13967037/

Comment: I posted a cleaner version of the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281914/spring-mvc4-http-404-not-found-error/34302539#34302539 and was able to get it resolved based on another poster's help. Thanks to Josh as well for his help and leading me in the right direction.